# 2 polynomial regressions in a ggplot() graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, polynomials

This is my Dataset:
[image: Dataset]

As you can see, there are two quantitative variables (X, Y) and 1 categorical variable (molar, with two factors: M1, M2).

I would like to represent in one single graph two polynomial regressions and their respective prediction intervals: one for the M1 factor and one for the M2 factor. Each polynomial regression has its own degree (M1 is a 4 degree polynomial regression, and M2 is a 6 degree).

I want to use ggplot() function (which is in package ggplot2 in R). I have actually performed this figure but with all data merged (I mean, with no distinction between factors). This is the code I used:

```
# Fit a linear model
m <- lm(Y ~ X+I(X^2)+I(X^3)+I(X^4), data = Dataset)
# cbind the predictions to Dataset
mpi <- cbind(Dataset, predict(m, interval = "prediction"))

ggplot(mpi, aes(x = X)) +
geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lwr, ymax = upr),
fill = "blue", alpha = 0.2) +
geom_point(aes(y = Y)) +
geom_line(aes(y = fit), colour = "blue", size = 1)
```

With this result:
[image: One single polynomial regression]

So, I would like to have two different-grade polynomial regressions (one for the M1 and one for the M2), taking into account their respective predictions intervals. Which would be the exact code?

---

UPDATE - New code! I run this code with no success:

```
M1=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M1",select=X:Y)
M2=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M2",select=X:Y)

M1.R <- lm(Y ~ X +I(X^2)+I(X^3)+I(X^4), 
data=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M1",select=X:Y))
M2.R <- lm(Y ~ X +I(X^2)+I(X^3)+I(X^4), 
data=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M2",select=X:Y))


newdf <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, c(408,663)))

M1.P <- cbind(data=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M1",select=X:Y), predict(M1.R, interval = "prediction"))
M2.P <- cbind(data=subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M2",select=X:Y), predict(M2.R, interval = "prediction"))

p = cbind(as.data.frame(rbind(M1.P, M2.P)), f = factor(rep(1:2, c(408,663)), x = rep(newdf$x, 2))

mdf = with(Dataset, data.frame(x = rep(x, 2), y = c(subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M1",select=Y), subset(Dataset,Dataset$molar=="M2",select=Y),
                   f = factor(rep(1:2, c(408,663))))


ggplot(mdf, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = f)) + geom_point() +
geom_ribbon(data = p, aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr,
                    fill = f, y = NULL, colour = NULL),
      alpha = 0.2) +

geom_line(data = p, aes(x = x, y = fit))
```

These are the messages I get now:

```
[98] WARNING: Warning in if (n < 0L) stop("wrong sign in 'by' argument") :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in if (n > .Machine$integer.max) stop("'by' argument is much too small") :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in 0L:n :
numerical expression has 2 elements: only the first used
Warning in if (by > 0) pmin(x, to) else pmax(x, to) :
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
[99] WARNING: Warning in predict.lm(M1.R, interval = "prediction") :
predictions on current data refer to _future_ responses
[100] WARNING: Warning in predict.lm(M2.R, interval = "prediction") :
predictions on current data refer to _future_ responses
[101] ERROR: <text>
```

I think I am closer but still can't see it. Help!

Comment: `ggplot(mpi, aes(x=X, y=Y, colour=molar)) + geom_point(alpha=0.4) + geom_smooth(method="lm", formula=y~poly(x,4))`

Comment: @eipi10 that will only give a confidence interval on the fitted curves, not the desired prediction interval. I don't think you can pass arguments to `predict.lm` to achieve this directly with `geom_smooth`.

Comment: Right eipi10. But every factor (M1 or M2) has its own polynomial equation (that differs in the number of degrees). As well, I would like to represent the prediction interval. Would you know which is the code to run what I want?

Comment: Ah, thanks @GavinSimpson. I missed that. I've added an answer that I hope meets the OP's needs.

Comment: It looks like your data are bounded at 100 at the upper level. Is this real or just an artifact here? If the data are bounded/truncated at the upper end (or lower, or both) then the linear model is not the right model, as evidence by the prediction interval exceeding those limits.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way. If you have more than two models/levels in the factor you should look into code that will work over the levels of the factor and fit the models that way.

Anyway, first some dummy data:

```
set.seed(100)
x <- runif(100)
y1 <- 2 + (0.3 * x) + (2.4 * x^2) + (-2.5 * x^3) + (3.4 * x^4) + rnorm(100)
y2 <- -1 + (0.3 * x) + (2.4 * x^2) + (-2.5 * x^3) + (3.4 * x^4) +
  (-0.3 * x^5) + (2.4 * x^6) + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(x, y1, y2)
```

Fit our two models:

```
m1 <- lm(y1 ~ poly(x, 4), data = df)
m2 <- lm(y2 ~ poly(x, 6), data = df)
```

Now precict at some new locations `x` and stick it together with `x` and `f`, a factor indexing the model, into a tidy format:

```
newdf <- data.frame(x = seq(0, 1, length = 100))
p1 <- predict(m1, newdata = newdf, interval = "prediction")
p2 <- predict(m2, newdata = newdf, interval = "prediction")
p <- cbind(as.data.frame(rbind(p1, p2)), f = factor(rep(1:2, each = 100)),
           x = rep(newdf$x, 2))
```

Melt the original data into tidy form

```
mdf <- with(df, data.frame(x = rep(x, 2), y = c(y1, y2),
                           f = factor(rep(1:2, each = 100))))
```

Draw the plot, using colour to distinguish the models/data

```
ggplot(mdf, aes(x = x, y = y, colour = f)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_ribbon(data = p, aes(x = x, ymin = lwr, ymax = upr,
                            fill = f, y = NULL, colour = NULL),
              alpha = 0.2) +
  geom_line(data = p, aes(x = x, y = fit))
```

This gets us

[image]

Comment: I tried your example, I got what I am expecting to obtain with my data. However, when applying to my personal data, I get several errors and I don't know how to solve them. I am answering my question subsequently with the code I run.